# How can I avoid creating multiple adapters (RecyclerView)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a layout that displays events for team members of each team. I use 8 `RecyclerViews`, all with same layout (two `TextViews`). First `TextView` shows the person name, while the second shows the minute of the event.

Four of those `RecyclerView` are for the events of team 1, while the other 4 are for the team 2. There are 4 kind of events, hence 4 type of events * 2 teams = 8 `RecyclerViews`.

My code works, but I think it can be optimized, as in the end every `RecyclerView` shows the same information and I always use the same `Adapter` (8 different instances). My idea is to have 1 layout containing 2 `RecyclerViews`, and use `<include layout="@layout/my_new_layout" />` 4 times in my `Fragment` layout to have the 8 `RecyclerViews`.

Then create a new class including two adapters and two `RecyclerView`, one for each team. I would create 4 instances of this new class, one for each event.

My problem is that I am not sure where to place this code. Should it go in my Fragment class or the new class?

```
this.firstEventHomeRv = v.findViewById(R.id.home_first_rv);
this.firstEventHomeRv.setHasFixedSize(true);
this.firstEventHomeRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

this.firstEventAwayRv = v.findViewById(R.id.away_first_rv);
this.firstEventAwayRv.setHasFixedSize(true);
this.firstEventAwayRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(),
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/1827254